# Compare list of values to range and index in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range, series

I'm trying to determine if the ID in one data frame to match those in a second dataframe, and if the values fall within the range contained in the second data frame. I haven't been able to find an answer to this, however, my python isn't strong so I apologize if I missed something that's already out there.
Here is an example of what the datframe look like.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID' : pd.Series(["A","A","C","C"]),
                    'Pos' : pd.Series([10, 60, 63, 105], dtype='int32')})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID' : pd.Series(["A","B","C","C","D"]),
                    'Start' : pd.Series([10, 40, 61, 100, 250], dtype='int32'),
                    'End' : pd.Series([12, 59, 62, 200, 300], dtype='int32')})
```

so for every row in df1 I would like to check if the ID is contained in df2, and if so, if the "Pos" in df1 falls withing the range of "Start" to "End" in df2.
i.e.

```
for value in df1["Pos"]:
    tmp_start=value >= df2["Start"]
    tmp_end=value <= df2["End"]
    tmp_ID=df1[df1['Pos']==[value]]["ID"].to_string(index=False) == df2["ID"]
    if any(tmp_start.multiply(tmp_end).multiply(tmp_ID)):
        print "Do Something" + value
```

So the above works but it not very fast and I'm sure theres a better way.

I also tried something like this, but it doesnt check the ID.

```
def range_test(x):
    return range(x[1], (x[2]+1))

df2 = df2.apply(range_test, axis=1) df2 = [st for row in cov for st in
row] df2 = list(set(df2.sort())) df1['Pos'].isin(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
In [34]: df1[(df1.ID.isin(df2.ID))&(df1.index.isin(df2.index))]
Out[34]: 
  ID  Pos
0  A   10
1  A   60
2  C   63
3  C  105
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't check if the "Pos" falls within the range of the "Start" and "End" in df2. Value 60 doesn't.